# Is there a function in R to take the last 30 seconds of a time reading before a break in the time recordings?

Tags: r, time

I am trying to create a function to take the last 30 readings before the break in time. I then want to average the readings to get a value for the set of 30 seconds.

This is an example of the data I have

```
time        concentration
10:29:19    1814.04
10:29:20    1815.80
10:29:21    1816.09
10:29:22    1817.52
10:29:23    1819.10
10:29:24    1818.25
10:29:25    1818.35
10:29:26    1819.10
10:29:27    1820.31
10:29:28    1819.63
10:29:29    1818.94
10:29:30    1818.91
10:29:31    1819.58
10:29:32    1818.73
10:29:33    1820.21
10:29:34    1821.64
10:29:35    1819.39
10:29:36    1818.52
10:29:37    1819.58
10:29:38    1820.27
10:29:39    1818.99
10:29:40    1819.77
10:29:41    1820.08
10:29:42    1820.13
10:29:43    1819.26
10:29:44    1820.50
10:29:45    1820.12
10:29:46    1818.45
10:29:47    1819.54      Here is the break in time. It jumps from 10:29:47 to 10:31:00
10:31:00    1129.30
10:31:01    2673.05
10:31:02    2492.65
10:31:03    2232.31
10:31:04    2190.14
```

This similar format is repeated for an hour's worth of readings.

photo of data [photo of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPVil.png)

Comment: There is no build in solution that I know of. However it should be reasonably easy to implement such a function yourself. Try giving it a go and then report how you approached the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest a tidyverse flow, since I infer that grouping is important here (and it is generally easy and intuitive within a `dplyr` pipe). Also, the strings you have for time-of-day are not easily comparable, so I'm going to convert them to a true timestamp (`POSIXt` in R-speak)[1].

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    time_psx = as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), time)), 
    grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(time_psx) > 1))
  ) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(time_psx >= max(time_psx) - 30) %>%
  summarize(
    time = last(time), 
    time_psx = last(time_psx), 
    n = n(), 
    mean = sum(concentration), 
    .groups = "drop"
  )
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#     grp time     time_psx                n   mean
#   <int> <chr>    <dttm>              <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1 10:29:47 2021-01-18 10:29:47    29 52751.
# 2     2 10:31:04 2021-01-18 10:31:04     5 10717.
```

This includes the last group, even if it is not technically followed by a gap. If you need to remove that, then we can add a single `filter`

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(
    time_psx = as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), time)), 
    grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(time_psx) > 1))
  ) %>%
  filter(grp < max(grp)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(time_psx >= max(time_psx) - 30) %>%
  summarize(
    time = last(time), 
    time_psx = last(time_psx), 
    n = n(), 
    mean = sum(concentration), 
    .groups = "drop"
  )
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#     grp time     time_psx                n   mean
#   <int> <chr>    <dttm>              <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1 10:29:47 2021-01-18 10:29:47    29 52751.
```

Note:

1. The conversion to `POSIXt` works, but will cause a logical problem if you have data that wraps over midnight. If you have a real "date" in your data, I urge you to include it in the sample data and in your conversion with `as.POSIXt` (in place of `Sys.Date()`).

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, just one edit to change mean= mean(concentration) instead of sum. Thanks for your help with this!